# C# Regular expression to get parenthesized info

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parentheses

I need a regular expression that will match text enclosed in parentheses. The parentheses should be included. Here are some examples.

String: "(AB123-16W) DJ2988W61"
Should match: "(AB123-16W)"

String: "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2) 62MJ301-29 Rev. NC"
Should match: "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test1 = "(AB123-16W) DJ2988W61";
var test2 = "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2) 62MJ301-29 Rev. NC";
var test3 = "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2)(AB123-16W)";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(\([^)]*\))");

var result1 = (r.Matches(test1)[0].Groups[1].Value == "(AB123-16W)");
var result2 = (r.Matches(test2)[0].Groups[1].Value == "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2)");
var result3 = (r.Matches(test3)[0].Groups[1].Value == "(6541238 Rev. B, PS B1 & PS B2)");
var result4 = (r.Matches(test3)[1].Groups[1].Value == "(AB123-16W)");

Debugger.Break();
```

All results variables will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(\(.*?\))/
```

Should match the items in parenthesis :D

You may not have to use the delimiters ( forward slashes ) in your language! Try with, and if that doesn't work, try without.

Comment: You might want a non-greedy version:
(\(.*?\))

since the greedy version with "Testing (123) Testing (123)" will match "(123) Testing (123)"

Comment: Unfortunately that did not return any matches.

Comment: @aquinas, your regular expression worked too. Thanks all for your help.